# Cannot install Windows on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, windows

I have a 2008 Macbook running Lion. I started up Boot Camp and it gave an error saying the startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.

I looked at Disk Utility and there was a partition named Lion which was taking up all 250 GB of space and I cannot resize it.

Also the OS X installation has no recovery drives or images, so the normal methods wont work.

Is there any way I could install Windows 10 on this machine without having to resort to VM or a clean reinstall?

Comment: How much of the 250GB are actually used?

Comment: You have to make a partition on your MacintoshHD. http://www.macworld.com/article/1164643/live_partition.html

Comment: Exactly—you can't just resize the Lion partition without having another partition available to use the space. You need to click the `+` button below the partition map, then go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry For not Responding For the Last few days.Unfortunately i had to format and reinstall Lion to install win 7.The hard drive was set up in such a way that it could not create a Boot Camp partition  even if only 20GBs of the 250 was used.

After Formatting the Drive as A journaled mac OS partition,I was able to install Win 7.

BTW i Could not make any changes to the drive before formatting.New partition,Restore etc. were all grayed out.